# Multiple Request Code for the same activity on Activity For Result

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Is it possible to have multiple request codes all of them starting the same activity? If so how to return the result with the correct calling request code?

```
 setResult(RESULT_OK, intent) ;
```

does pass the request code per my understanding but how can the onActivityResult know which key initiated the intent?
like

```
if(int j ==0 ){
   startActivityResult(intent,0);
 } else if(j ==1 ){
   startActivityResult(intent,1);
 } else if(j ==3 ){
   startActivityResult(intent,3);
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly fine. [`onActivityResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) receives the request code as the first of its arguments, so you can check it there. You should create constants for your request codes and refer to those in your code instead of hardcoded values like the sample you posted.

```
private static final int REQUEST_SOMETHING = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_SOMETHING_ELSE = 2; // etc

if (j == REQUEST_SOMETHING) {
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SOMETHING);
else if (j == REQUEST_SOMETHING_ELSE) {
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SOMETHING_ELSE);
} // etc

@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_SOMETHING:
            // do something
            break;
        case REQUEST_SOMETHING_ELSE:
            // do something else
            break;
        // etc.
    }
}
```